# How to make a wordpress website without comments block?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I can make website in Wordpress, but on every page There is a comment box section, I want to remove those comment section, Please tell me how can I?
On every post and page There is a comment option(section) like a Blog is having.
Please tell me the solution.
 Actually I have learnt wordpress by my self and with help of Internet and from your site as well. Thats why I dont know how to remove that comment section from my website.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: A) Remove it from your Template B)  Disable in the Settings

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, try instructions at https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-comments-feature/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to remove one line of code from the page template that calls the comments.

If you are using the Twenty Ten theme you would open the loop-page.php file. Locate (2nd last line) and remove the line

```
<!–?php comments_template( ”, true ); ?–>
```

If you are using the Twenty Twelve theme you would open the page.php file and find the same line of code.

Students using a LearnWP custom theme simply need to select a page template. “Default template” will include comments, any other template in our theme has page comments removed.